# Converting String to JSONArray with SwiftyJson crashes

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I am already saturated looking into other solutions but none will work, so here it goes:
I want to convert this *STRING VALUE* , I repeat: STRING VALUE, to a JSONObject or JSONArray:

```
[["demo": "Default", "tint": "ff00fd", "icon": "http://someurl.com/icon.jpg", "language": "en-US", "endpoint": "http://pres.artifutions.com/traveldemoapp/", "title": "Travel Demo"], ["demo": "Demo 2", "tint": "ff99fd", "icon": "http://someurl.com/icon.jpg", "language": "en-US", "endpoint": "http://pres.artifutions.com/traveldemoapp/", "title": "Second Demo"], ["demo": "Demo 3", "tint": "ff99fd", "icon": "http://someurl.com/icon.jpg", "language": "en-US", "endpoint": "http://pres.artifutions.com/traveldemoapp/", "title": "Third Demo"], ["demo": "Demo 4", "tint": "ff99fd", "icon": "http://someurl.com/icon.jpg", "language": "en-US", "endpoint": "http://pres.artifutions.com/traveldemoapp/", "title": "Fourth Demo"], ["title": "zz", "tint": "ff00fd", "icon": "(default)", "language": "nld-NLD", "endpoint": "http://pres.artifutions.com/traveldemoapp/", "demo": "z"], ["demo": "Add Demo..."]]
```

When I try to convert that string to a JSON Object, with this code, it crashes:

```
let jConfigs = JSON(myString).array
        print("=======json")
        print(jConfigs![0])
```

What is the problem? Converting that into  `Dictionary<String,String>` would also work fine for me.

**UPDATE:**
The accepted answer works, I used replace() to clean the input string.
Plus, I did an extra step to complete the conversion of the String into a JSON array. Note that in my case, I cannot control how the string comes, it is as it -is-.

```
            var ss=InputString.replace("], [",withString: "}, {")
            ss=ss.replace("[[",withString: "[{")
            ss=ss.replace("]]",withString: "}]")
            if let data = ss.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                do{
                    if let array = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)  as? [AnyObject] {
                       print(array)
                       }
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: What string? I see an array of dictionaries, not a JSON string. You want `Dictionary<String,String>` but it is already `[Dictionary<String,String>]`, you don't need SwiftyJSON, just access the array. There's no JSON in this question.

Comment: @EricD. It IS a string, the string representation of a [Dictionary<String,String>] in any case. The Question is: How can I convert it to a JSON object or to a Dictionary object?

Comment: @EricD. It IS there, if you don't skim through the reading I have underlined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided invalid json format.

Correct one (curly braces for object):

[**{**"demo": "Default", "tint": "ff00fd", "icon": "http://someurl.com/icon.jpg", "language": "en-US", "endpoint": "http://pres.artifutions.com/traveldemoapp/", "title": "Travel Demo"**}**, **{**"demo": "Demo 2", "tint": "ff99fd", "icon": "http://someurl.com/icon.jpg", "language": "en-US", "endpoint": "http://pres.artifutions.com/traveldemoapp/", "title": "Second Demo"**}**]

Comment: You where right, the fault is not so visible, and I cannot control how the string arrives like that. Furthermore, for those interested, I have added an extra step, to convert the whole thing into a JSON shaped array.